# Log each method call in Kohana?

Tags: kohana

How can I log each method call in controllers and models in my Kohana application?

I would like to clean up my scripts and remove unused methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `before()` and `after()` methods to log your controller name & action (use `$this->request` to get these values).

There is no such methods for models, but I dont like using `__call()` for this purpose. May be you should log your models in controllers? Like this:

```
// somewhere in controller 
$cid = $this->request->param('cat_id');
// call custom model method
$articles = ORM::factory('article')->get_by_category($cid);
// log model call
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Kohana_Controller and Kohana_Model with the following:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    // Log call here

    // Now return the real method
    return parent::__call($name, $arguments)
}
```

__call() is fairly slow, so you'll want to remove these eventually.

Comment: Isn't __call() called only when undefined object method is called?

Comment: You are right, I had a brain fart! :( Use biakaveron's suggestion.